# CSS: Select all first generation elements (children), but not grandchildren

Tags: css

Given this unordered list:

```
<ul>
  <li>Level One Item One
    <ul>
      <li>Level One Item One</li>
      <li>Level One Item Two</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Level One Item Two
    <ul>
      <li>Level Two Item One</li>
      <li>Level Two Item Two</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

... I would like to apply a style to all immediate `<li>` children of an `<ul>`, without having that style applied to nested list items.

I thought this CSS selector would do the trick, but it has no effect:

```
ul>li:not(li>ul>li) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Here is a fiddle:

[image: Picture of a fiddle]

Just kidding, here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nz5fdnd0/1/

Here is a picture of the desired outcome:

[image: Screen shot of desired outcome]

The desired solution would avoid using explicit class or id attributes in the HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use

```
:not(li) > ul > li {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

which means target the `li` in a `ul` that is not contained (*directly*) in a `li`.

So keep in mind that if inside a li you add a `div` and in that a `ul li` it will get styled.

---

```css
:not(li) > ul > li {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Level One Item One
    <ul>
      <li>Level One Item One</li>
      <li>Level One Item Two</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Level One Item Two
    <ul>
      <li>Level Two Item One</li>
      <li>Level Two Item Two</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution I found is to add an outer `<div>` and then target the first child of that:

```css
div > ul > li {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Level One Item One
      <ul>
        <li>Level One Item One</li>
        <li>Level One Item Two</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Level One Item Two
      <ul>
        <li>Level Two Item One</li>
        <li>Level Two Item Two</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't use any fancy :not selectors, ah well such is life.

Comment: You can also put a class on the `ul` you want to target and do `ul.myclass > li`

Comment: Even though _"The desired solution would avoid using explicit class or id attributes in the HTML"_ I would go with a class rather than introducing an enclosing `div` just for the purposes of style. However, if the outer `ul` is _already_ (always) in a div ...

Comment: Yes that would be simplest, but the source is being generated from Markdown, so it's hard to add a class. Adding the div container is trivial, so I'll go with that.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use

```
ul:not(:only-child) > li {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

This will work if your parent `<ul>` element has siblings.

---

```css
ul:not(:only-child) > li {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Level One Item One
    <ul>
      <li>Level One Item One</li>
      <li>Level One Item Two</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Level One Item Two
    <ul>
      <li>Level Two Item One</li>
      <li>Level Two Item Two</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ul li {
  border: 1px solid red;
}   
 ul:first-child ul li{
   border: none;
 }
```

Comment: No that doesn't return any elements. Good try though.

Comment: Sorry for that, I thought this was something you are looking for :)

Comment: After your edit it actually does work, so this could be an answer.